# Reading file in Java error

Tags: java, io

Hey whenever I try to read this file i get

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Not sure what im doing wrong

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));
```

I am sure the file is in right place and still not working... Spend quite a lot of time looking at this and not sure what I'm doing wrong and I bet the mistake is right under my nose...

Comment: file not found means file not found. you cannot be in the right place. try `new FileReader("/complete/path/to/data.txt")`

Comment: there's really not enough here to go on. You say the file is there, Java says it isn't. Clearly one of you is wrong. I would try specifying the full path, just to get started, and work from there.

Comment: MY BAD! i accidentally added .txt on my file even though it was already .txt so the file was really data.txt.txt DERP!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following to print out the working directory that Java is using:

```
   System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

If this isn't the directory containing your file, then you have found the problem!

Java will try to find `data.txt` by starting from the *working directory*, not necessarily from the location of your program.

You may be running the program from another directory, either because that's the current directory of your console, or the location of a script that calls Java, or because of a setting in your IDE (it depends how you are running the program).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this code instead:

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
```

Hope this helps!